# github等でタグを作成する際にソースコード内のバージョンが上がっていないとタグを作成されないようにするには？

Tags: git, github

タイトルの通りですが、具体的には

[AssemblyInfo.cs#L55-L56](https://github.com/bamchoh/jupiter/blob/d34378576ceb6cdba7db6ac6fd9fe669d5146237/Jupiter/Properties/AssemblyInfo.cs#L55-L56)

```cs
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("0.1.0.9")]
[assembly: AssemblyInformationalVersion("0.1.0.9")]
```

ここのバージョンが上がってないとタグを切れなくしたいです。

Comment: タグには、バージョン管理等に使われる anotated tag と、一時的にメモをしておくための lightweight tag が[存在します](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E5%9F%BA%E6%9C%AC-%E3%82%BF%E3%82%B0)。おそらくこの質問では anotated tag を想定されていて、更にタグを切ることとそのタグに対応するバージョンをリリースすることが同じ意味を持つのでこのような質問になったのではないかと推測するのですが、あっていますでしょうか？

Comment: @nekketsuuu ですです。あってます。タグに種類があったのは知りませんでした。知見だぁ。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

該当箇所 (バージョン番号) の変更がされていない場合、ムダなコミットを増やさないためにも
「タグ付け」の際に**自動で**弾いて欲しい、という事であれば [Git Hooks](https://git-scm.com/book/ja/v2/Git-%E3%81%AE%E3%82%AB%E3%82%B9%E3%82%BF%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BA-Git-%E3%83%95%E3%83%83%E3%82%AF) の仕組みが使えそうです。

Gitで特定の操作を実行した際に、カスタムスクリプトを実行する方法です。

Comment: やっぱりそのあたりでやっていくしかないですよね。既に同じようなことを困ってる人がいそうなのでgithub検索してみます。